# conditional summarising/mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping, summarize

Trying to conditionally sum based on the previous groupings. Having trouble coming up with it.

I'm trying to sum the amt column based on which ones are in type r1, after grouping by f.

Reproducible code:

```
s <- sample(c('one', 'two'), 96, replace = TRUE)
f <- sample(c('a','s','d','f'), 96, replace = TRUE)
r1_amt <- runif(96, 1, 100)
r2_amt <- runif(96, 1, 100)
r3_amt <- runif(96, 1, 100)
x <- data_frame(s, f, r1_amt, r2_amt, r3_amt)


smy <- x %>%
  group_by(f) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), # population in each f group
            num_r1 = sum(r1_amt >= 50)) # amount of r1 in each f group
```

I've tried `.[r1_amt >= 50]$amt`, `cumsum(r1_amt >= 50)`, `sum(ifelse(r1_amt >= 50, r1_amt, 0))` but haven't been able to come up with the grouped numbers.

So 1 given row could be a 60 for r1, 40 for r2, and 55 for r3 and it should be included in the summed amount column for only r1 and r3 if that makes sense.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I adjusted the reproducible example, as I hadn't made it quite correctly. I want to classify a given observation as being r1 if it has over 50 in the r1_amt. And then the sum_r1_amt column should be the sum of the r1_amt, only if the observation is above 50.

Comment: @MattW. If you want to change your question, ask another one as a follow up. It's not professional to come back after 16 hours and edit your question. It is not that hard to modify my answer to address your new inquiry but I would leave that to you or, maybe, other answers.

Comment: To make your code reproducible, consider doing a `set.seed(10)` at the beginning so that we will get the same answer when reproducing.  Better yet would be to make an example simple enough that you can compute by hand what the answer is to make it easier to understand what the desired output is.

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible in a bit cleaner way too, but this should work:

```
x.v2 <- x # temp variable
x.v2[which(x[,4] != 'r1'),3] <- 0 # replace values of tpe != 'r1' with 0's 

smy <- x.v2 %>%
            group_by(f) %>%
            summarise(n = n(), # population in each f group
            num_r1 = sum(amt)) # sum of values for type == 'r1' in each group f

rm(x.v2) # remove temp variable

smy # output for seed = 123 (use set.seed(123) for building data)


#   f  n   num_r1
# 1 a 20 114.1879
# 2 d 28 611.9858
# 3 f 19 351.5366
# 4 s 29 357.8402
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is just group by both f and type to compute the per-f/type statistics.

```
x %>% group_by(f, type) %>% summarise(num_type=n(), sum_type=sum(amt))
Source: local data frame [16 x 4]
Groups: f [?]

       f  type num_type   sum_type
   <chr> <chr>    <int>      <dbl>
1      a    r1       12   616.6610
2      a    r2        6   417.5589
3      a    r3        9   375.2246
4      a    r4        7   346.5796
5      d    r1        8   471.1253
...
```

You can use `tidyr` to go back to wide form for the `sum_type` field, but I would only do so for display purposes:

```
> res %>% spread(type, sum_amt)
Source: local data frame [12 x 6]
Groups: f [4]

       f num_type       r1       r2       r3       r4
*  <chr>    <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1      a        6       NA 417.5589       NA       NA
2      a        7       NA       NA       NA 346.5796
3      a        9       NA       NA 375.2246       NA
...
```

Comment: You're definitely right. I realize I didn't really create the reproducible example correctly because grouping makes the most sense. Let me edit to clarify